# command FIND in BASH how to change it

Tags: bash

In my script of backups  i have this command :

```
find $HOME/folha1/it/backups/ -type f -mmin +15 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

He works, but i want to change that.
I want to implement the next scenary:

when i have 5 or plus files in that diretory, i want to delete the older's.

I don't know how to change that, with this command, i use man find but i didn't understand well.

Anybody know how to dele older's backups with the command find?

```
!/bin/bash
DIR="/home/teste/folha1/it/backups"
  if [ -d "$DIR" ]; then
          echo "Diretory Exist"
  else
  bash -c "mkdir -p /home/teste/folha1/it/backups/"
  echo "Created Diretory"
  exit 1
fi
zip -rv $HOME/folha1/it/backups/scripts$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S_%N).bck.zip $HOME/folha1/it/scripts
```

And then i want to put next the command find

```
find $HOME/folha1/it/backups/ -type f -mmin +15 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: Hi, José. Can you clearly state what you want to do? If the specified directory contains 5 or more files, you want to delete the oldest file? That's all?

Comment: es, i want to change the command find to delete the oldest when i have 5 ou more files @Quasímodo

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
TARGET_DIR=$HOME/folha1/it/backups
#Lets count how many there are
COUNT=`find $TARGET_DIR -type f -mmin +15 | wc -l`
#If there are more than 5, let's delete oldest files except newest 5
if [ "$COUNT" -gt "5" ]; then
   cd $TARGET_DIR; rm `ls -t $TARGET_DIR  | awk 'NR>5'`
fi
```

Comment: hey, this not delete but its a start, i will modificate and test